# ubuntu 10.04 boot script finished, but shell or xwindow not shown

Tags: operating-system, ubuntu-10.04, boot

After I automate update my ubuntu from 9.10 --> 10.04 , I can not enter in the system, when the start script executed finished. Nothing comes up.

Then I used a boot ISO entered the system, mount the file system, find boot.log, daemon.log and syslog are all normal.

Why exactly this would happen and how can I fix it? I have grub already installed, may I use it to recover my kernel? If can, how to start up it?

The newest situation here's the daemon log.

```
Apr 20 14:41:02 BJ-IT-Leona avahi-daemon[3212]: Found user 'avahi' (UID 105) and group 'avahi' (GID 111).
Apr 20 14:41:02 BJ-IT-Leona avahi-daemon[3212]: Successfully dropped root privileges.
Apr 20 14:41:02 BJ-IT-Leona init: apport pre-start process (3219) terminated with status 1
Apr 20 14:41:02 BJ-IT-Leona avahi-daemon[3212]: avahi-daemon 0.6.25 starting up.
Apr 20 14:41:02 BJ-IT-Leona avahi-daemon[3212]: Successfully called chroot().
Apr 20 14:41:02 BJ-IT-Leona avahi-daemon[3212]: Successfully dropped remaining capabilities.
Apr 20 14:41:02 BJ-IT-Leona init: apport post-stop process (3230) terminated with status 1
Apr 20 14:41:02 BJ-IT-Leona NetworkManager: <info>  starting...
Apr 20 14:41:02 BJ-IT-Leona avahi-daemon[3212]: No service file found in /etc/avahi/services.
Apr 20 14:41:02 BJ-IT-Leona NetworkManager: <info>  Trying to start the modem-manager...
Apr 20 14:41:02 BJ-IT-Leona NetworkManager:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: init!
Apr 20 14:41:02 BJ-IT-Leona NetworkManager:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: update_system_hostname
Apr 20 14:41:02 BJ-IT-Leona NetworkManager:    SCPluginIfupdown: management mode: unmanaged
Apr 20 14:41:02 BJ-IT-Leona NetworkManager:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:02:00.0/net/eth0, iface: eth0)
Apr 20 14:41:02 BJ-IT-Leona NetworkManager:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:02:00.0/net/eth0, iface: eth0): no ifupdown configuration found.
Apr 20 14:41:02 BJ-IT-Leona NetworkManager:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/lo, iface: lo)
Apr 20 14:41:02 BJ-IT-Leona NetworkManager:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/lo, iface: lo): no ifupdown configuration found.
Apr 20 14:41:02 BJ-IT-Leona NetworkManager:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: end _init.
Apr 20 14:41:02 BJ-IT-Leona NetworkManager: Loaded plugin ifupdown: (C) 2008 Canonical Ltd.  To report bugs please use the NetworkManager mailing list.
Apr 20 14:41:02 BJ-IT-Leona NetworkManager: Loaded plugin keyfile: (c) 2007 - 2008 Red Hat, Inc.  To report bugs please use the NetworkManager mailing list.
Apr 20 14:41:02 BJ-IT-Leona gdm-binary[3238]: WARNING: Unable to load file '/etc/gdm/custom.conf': No such file or directory
Apr 20 14:41:02 BJ-IT-Leona init: gdm main process (3238) killed by ABRT signal
Apr 20 14:41:02 BJ-IT-Leona NetworkManager: <info>  Wireless now enabled by radio killswitch
Apr 20 14:41:02 BJ-IT-Leona NetworkManager:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: (16638240) ... get_connections.
Apr 20 14:41:02 BJ-IT-Leona NetworkManager:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: (16638240) ... get_connections (managed=false): return empty list.
Apr 20 14:41:02 BJ-IT-Leona NetworkManager:    Ifupdown: get unmanaged devices count: 0
Apr 20 14:41:02 BJ-IT-Leona NetworkManager: <info>  (eth0): carrier is OFF
Apr 20 14:41:02 BJ-IT-Leona NetworkManager: <info>  (eth0): new Ethernet device (driver: 'tg3')
Apr 20 14:41:02 BJ-IT-Leona NetworkManager: <info>  (eth0): exported as /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/0
Apr 20 14:41:02 BJ-IT-Leona NetworkManager: <info>  (eth0): now managed
Apr 20 14:41:02 BJ-IT-Leona NetworkManager: <info>  (eth0): device state change: 1 -> 2 (reason 2)
Apr 20 14:41:02 BJ-IT-Leona NetworkManager: <info>  (eth0): bringing up device.
Apr 20 14:41:02 BJ-IT-Leona NetworkManager: <info>  (eth0): preparing device.
Apr 20 14:41:02 BJ-IT-Leona NetworkManager: <info>  (eth0): deactivating device (reason: 2).
Apr 20 14:41:02 BJ-IT-Leona NetworkManager: <WARN>  default_adapter_cb(): bluez error getting default adapter: The name org.bluez was not provided by any .service files
Apr 20 14:41:02 BJ-IT-Leona NetworkManager: <info>  Trying to start the supplicant...
Apr 20 14:41:02 BJ-IT-Leona avahi-daemon[3212]: Network interface enumeration completed.
Apr 20 14:41:02 BJ-IT-Leona avahi-daemon[3212]: Registering HINFO record with values 'X86_64'/'LINUX'.
Apr 20 14:41:02 BJ-IT-Leona avahi-daemon[3212]: Server startup complete. Host name is BJ-IT-Leona.local. Local service cookie is 2991573143.
Apr 20 14:41:03 BJ-IT-Leona acpid: client connected from 3399[107:114]
Apr 20 14:41:03 BJ-IT-Leona NetworkManager:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/vboxnet0, iface: vboxnet0)
Apr 20 14:41:03 BJ-IT-Leona NetworkManager:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/vboxnet0, iface: vboxnet0): no ifupdown configuration found.
Apr 20 14:41:03 BJ-IT-Leona NetworkManager: <WARN>  device_creator(): /sys/devices/virtual/net/vboxnet0: couldn't determine device driver; ignoring...
Apr 20 14:41:04 BJ-IT-Leona NetworkManager: <info>  (eth0): carrier now ON (device state 2)
Apr 20 14:41:04 BJ-IT-Leona NetworkManager: <info>  (eth0): device state change: 2 -> 3 (reason 40)
Apr 20 14:41:04 BJ-IT-Leona NetworkManager: <info>  Activation (eth0) starting connection 'Auto eth0'
Apr 20 14:41:04 BJ-IT-Leona NetworkManager: <info>  (eth0): device state change: 3 -> 4 (reason 0)
Apr 20 14:41:04 BJ-IT-Leona NetworkManager: <info>  Activation (eth0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
Apr 20 14:41:04 BJ-IT-Leona NetworkManager: <info>  Activation (eth0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
Apr 20 14:41:04 BJ-IT-Leona NetworkManager: <info>  Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
Apr 20 14:41:04 BJ-IT-Leona NetworkManager: <info>  Activation (eth0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
Apr 20 14:41:04 BJ-IT-Leona NetworkManager: <info>  Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
Apr 20 14:41:04 BJ-IT-Leona NetworkManager: <info>  (eth0): device state change: 4 -> 5 (reason 0)
Apr 20 14:41:04 BJ-IT-Leona NetworkManager: <info>  Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.
Apr 20 14:41:04 BJ-IT-Leona NetworkManager: <info>  Activation (eth0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) scheduled.
Apr 20 14:41:04 BJ-IT-Leona NetworkManager: <info>  Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
Apr 20 14:41:04 BJ-IT-Leona NetworkManager: <info>  Activation (eth0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) started...
Apr 20 14:41:04 BJ-IT-Leona NetworkManager: <info>  (eth0): device state change: 5 -> 7 (reason 0)
Apr 20 14:41:04 BJ-IT-Leona NetworkManager: <info>  Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IP4 Configure Get) scheduled...
Apr 20 14:41:04 BJ-IT-Leona NetworkManager: <info>  Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IP6 Configure Get) scheduled...
Apr 20 14:41:04 BJ-IT-Leona NetworkManager: <info>  Activation (eth0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) complete.
Apr 20 14:41:04 BJ-IT-Leona NetworkManager: <info>  Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IP4 Configure Get) started...
Apr 20 14:41:04 BJ-IT-Leona NetworkManager: <info>  Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IP4 Configure Get) complete.
Apr 20 14:41:04 BJ-IT-Leona NetworkManager: <info>  Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IP6 Configure Get) started...
Apr 20 14:41:04 BJ-IT-Leona NetworkManager: <info>  Activation (eth0) Stage 5 of 5 (IP Configure Commit) scheduled...
Apr 20 14:41:04 BJ-IT-Leona NetworkManager: <info>  Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IP6 Configure Get) complete.
Apr 20 14:41:04 BJ-IT-Leona NetworkManager: <info>  Activation (eth0) Stage 5 of 5 (IP Configure Commit) started...
Apr 20 14:41:04 BJ-IT-Leona avahi-daemon[3212]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv4 with address 172.23.5.249.
Apr 20 14:41:04 BJ-IT-Leona avahi-daemon[3212]: New relevant interface eth0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Apr 20 14:41:04 BJ-IT-Leona avahi-daemon[3212]: Registering new address record for 172.23.5.249 on eth0.IPv4.
Apr 20 14:41:05 BJ-IT-Leona mysqld_safe: Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
Apr 20 14:41:05 BJ-IT-Leona NetworkManager: <info>  (eth0): device state change: 7 -> 8 (reason 0)
Apr 20 14:41:05 BJ-IT-Leona NetworkManager: <info>  Policy set 'Auto eth0' (eth0) as default for routing and DNS.
Apr 20 14:41:05 BJ-IT-Leona NetworkManager: <info>  Activation (eth0) successful, device activated.
Apr 20 14:41:05 BJ-IT-Leona NetworkManager: <info>  Activation (eth0) Stage 5 of 5 (IP Configure Commit) complete.
Apr 20 14:41:05 BJ-IT-Leona avahi-daemon[3212]: Registering new address record for fe80::223:aeff:fe67:fa0 on eth0.*.
Apr 20 14:43:03 BJ-IT-Leona NetworkManager: <info>  Trying to start the supplicant...
Apr 20 14:45:03 BJ-IT-Leona NetworkManager: <info>  Trying to start the supplicant...
Apr 20 14:47:03 BJ-IT-Leona NetworkManager: <info>  Trying to start the supplicant...
```

The last NetworkManager "Trying to start the supplicant... " keeps running again and again and it never stop (I leave it alone last night for 8 hours and I get the daemon.log record it.)

What supplicant it trying to start? How can I fix it or just ignoring it ??

Comment: This does not seem to be related to programming question -- more like a superuser question geared for enthusiasts who can help you out with your problem. Did you create your own start script? Maybe this question will stay here if you share the code with us.

Comment: I have no code but daemon logs tell the situation . It's my bad that I forgot to parse it before.

Answer (score 0):

I reinstall the ubuntu . The problem has been gone... But I still don't know what happened...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your iso file has either moved or gotten corrupted. Try to keep your system updated, files trimmed and pkgs purged of what you no longer need.